# Problem with transforming a tophat to obtain a sinc?

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, filter-design, fourier

I have observed that the Fourier transform of a *tophat* function is a *Sinc*-like function with higher peak sidelobes than an actual *Sinc*.
However, the Fourier transform of a *Sinc* is a *tophat*-like function with ripples in both pass-band and stop-band, and with slow transition.

My question is: why does obtaining a *Sinc* from Fourier-transforming a *tophat* produce sub-optimal results?

Comment: Are you using an actual Fourier transform, continuous-time to continuous-time, or are you using an FFT?  Please **edit your question** if so.  _They are different things_.  If you're trying to use the FFT to experimentally learn about the Fourier transform, remember that you can gain _some_ insights, but using the FFT in that manner is only an approximation, not the real thing.

Comment: Yes I am applying an FFT.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using an FFT for your calucaltions.

If you use an FFT, it's aliasing. The FFT implements the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) for which both domains are discrete and periodic. You can't sample a sinc() function without aliasing. If you want to reproduce the text book relationship you have to use either the continuous Fourier Transform or the Discrete Time Fourier Transform. Sometimes the DFT is a good numerical approximation but sometimes it's not .

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform decomposes a signal into a sum of weighted sinusoidal components. It basically gives you the amplitude (and phase) of the frequency components present in your signal.

A *top-hat* signal has **infinitely sharp edges**.
What frequencies make up an infinitely sharp edge? Answer is an **infinite number of frequencies**.

That's why Fourier-transforming a *top-hat* will give you an *Sinc* that decays slowly, hence will have high side-lobes (but skinny main-lobe!). I suggest you take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHT2ONjtoh8) for a good visual explanation.

---

**Side-note**:
That's the reason why when taking the FFT of a signal, in most cases (not all!) it's recommended to apply a **[window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function)** that's NOT rectangular (not a *top-hat*), since you can find a better main-lobe-width / peak side lobe compromise than what the *top-hat* window gives you.

---

**EDIT**

From @Hilmar's answer I now realize what your question really was, wondering why you couldn't match a textbook representation to a computed result. I'll leave my answer here for posterity but @Hilmar's is the correct answer to your particular question :)

Comment: So is there a best tophat approximation one can get in practice? Besides increasing filter older/ window length?